# What is the name of the base form of and adjective?

Tags: grammar

Adjectives are found in different forms, among which *comparative* and *superlative*. However, is there a term to describe adjectives' "base form" (is "base form" the right term to coin them)?

Example:

> Circle adjectives with different colors depending on whether they are
>   written in their comparative, superlative or base form.

Comment: For *painted door*, are there *painteder door* and *paintedest door*?

Answer (score 3):

> The grammatical category associated with comparison of adjectives and adverbs is [degree of comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_%28grammar%29). The usual degrees of comparison are the **positive** ... the comparative ... and the superlative.